# SQL Server - Selecting random rows in batches for page numbering without duplicates

Tags: php, sql-server, pagination

I have the below query which extracts random rows without duplicates.

My issue is, when I want to load more for subsequent pages, how do I avoid getting duplicates?

```
SELECT TOP ($limit) Min(c.id)           AS id, 
                    s.id                AS skid, 
                    s.name, 
                    Min(b.sector)       AS sector, 
                    Min(s.currency)     AS currency, 
                    Min(s.url)          AS url, 
                    Min(sd.description) AS description 
FROM   coupons AS c 
       INNER JOIN users AS s 
               ON c.USER = s.id 
       INNER JOIN business AS b 
               ON s.id = b.USER 
       LEFT JOIN groups AS g 
              ON g.couponid = c.id 
WHERE  ( c.[public] = 'True' ) 
       AND ( c.valid = 'True' ) 
       AND ( s.currency = '$curr' ) 
GROUP  BY s.id, 
          s.name 
ORDER  BY Newid()
```

Many thanks

Comment: In reviewing my answer more carefully I've seen it was simply wrong. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: 1) How do you do anything randomly in this query? I don't see anything like `rand()`. Is it the `NewID()`? 2) where is this query referring to anything like pages (which you mention in the text)?

Comment: ORDER BY NewID() randomises the results.  I bring out 50 per page.  Therefore the first $limit value is 50 and so is the 2nd etc.  This will be the issue as I have no way of selecting ecords 1- 50 for page 1 anfd then 50 - 100 for page 2 and so on...

Comment: Have you thought of selecting defined set of records rather than random? In other words is randomness a requirement or workaround? There are ways to select defined set of records for paginated results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must save the returned record ids in an array and send them as a parameter when you load new data.

If you want to solve it with only sql, you may create a temporary table to save returned record ids. When you load more data simply add this:

```
"SELECT TOP ($limit) Min(c.id)           AS id, 
                s.id                AS skid, 
                s.name, 
                Min(b.sector)       AS sector, 
                Min(s.currency)     AS currency, 
                Min(s.url)          AS url, 
                Min(sd.description) AS description 
FROM   coupons AS c 
   INNER JOIN users AS s 
           ON c.USER = s.id 
   INNER JOIN business AS b 
           ON s.id = b.USER 
   LEFT JOIN groups AS g 
          ON g.couponid = c.id 
WHERE  ( c.[public] = 'True' ) 
   AND ( c.valid = 'True' ) 
   AND ( s.currency = '$curr' ) 
   AND ( s.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temporary_table))
GROUP  BY s.id, 
      s.name 
ORDER  BY Newid()";
```

If you are allowed to use php than it is easier. Just use an array variable and post it when you connect to loading page.

```
"SELECT TOP ($limit) Min(c.id)           AS id, 
                s.id                AS skid, 
                s.name, 
                Min(b.sector)       AS sector, 
                Min(s.currency)     AS currency, 
                Min(s.url)          AS url, 
                Min(sd.description) AS description 
FROM   coupons AS c 
   INNER JOIN users AS s 
           ON c.USER = s.id 
   INNER JOIN business AS b 
           ON s.id = b.USER 
   LEFT JOIN groups AS g 
          ON g.couponid = c.id 
WHERE  ( c.[public] = 'True' ) 
   AND ( c.valid = 'True' ) 
   AND ( s.currency = '$curr' ) 
   AND ( s.id NOT IN (" . implode(',', $used_Ids) ."))
GROUP  BY s.id, 
      s.name 
ORDER  BY Newid()";
```